# Xamarin Forms : How to Handle Listview Image Click Event in ViewModel?

Tags: xamarin.forms

All,

I am binding my Listview to a collection from a Viewmodel. CellView of the ListView includes an image. I would like to invoke a command in my viewmodel when I click the image in the list item.I am trying to avoid event handling in my model. Any idea ?

thanks !

Given below is the xaml and view model.

```
ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:jList="clr-namespace:JList;assembly=JList"
         x:Class="JList.Pages.ItemDetailPage"
         Title="Sub Items"
          BindingContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=ItemDetailViewModel}"
         >

<ContentPage.ToolbarItems >
    <ToolbarItem Text="Add" Order="Primary" Priority="1" Command="{Binding AddItemCommand}"></ToolbarItem>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Edit"  Order="Primary" Priority="2" Command="{Binding EditItemCommand}"></ToolbarItem>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
<StackLayout>
<SearchBar Placeholder="Search..." VerticalOptions="Fill" SearchCommand="{Binding SearchCommand}" Text="{Binding SearchString}" ></SearchBar>
<ListView RowHeight="200" ItemsSource="{Binding SubItemsCollection}"  BackgroundColor="Gainsboro" SelectedItem="{Binding SubItemSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" x:Name="List" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell >
               <StackLayout>
                   <Grid  VerticalOptions="Fill" BackgroundColor="White" Padding="5">
                       <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                           <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                       <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                           <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                       </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image  Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Aspect="AspectFit">                           
                       <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Chocolate" Font="Bold,20" />
                   </Grid>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
</StackLayout>
<ContentPage.Behaviors>

    <jList:CustomBehavior />

</ContentPage.Behaviors>
```

View Model

```
    namespace JList.Core.ViewModels
{
    public class ItemDetailViewModel : ViewModelBase, IViewModel
    {
        private IItemService _itemService;
        private ICommandFactory _cmdFactory;
        private INavigationService _navService;
        private ItemListViewModel _parent;
        private IAppInstanceData _appData;

        public ItemDetailViewModel(IItemService itemService, ICommandFactory cmdFactory, INavigationService navService, IAppInstanceData appData, ItemListViewModel parent)
        {
            _itemService = itemService;
            _cmdFactory = cmdFactory;
            _navService = navService;
            _parent = parent;
            ParentItemSelected = _parent.ItemSelected.Id;
            _appData = appData;
            // FetchSubItemsAsync();
        }


        public int ParentItemSelected { get; set; }

        private string _searchString;
        public String SearchString
        {
            get { return _searchString; }
            set
            {
                if (_searchString != value)
                {
                    _searchString = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<SubItem> _subItemsCollection;

        public ObservableCollection<SubItem> SubItemsCollection
        {
            get { return _subItemsCollection; }
            set
            {
                if (_subItemsCollection != null)
                {
                    if (!_subItemsCollection.SequenceEqual(value))
                    {
                        _subItemsCollection = value;
                        OnPropertyChanged();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    _subItemsCollection = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        private async void FetchSubItemsAsync()
        {
            ParentItemSelected = _parent.ItemSelected.Id;
            var items = await _itemService.GetAllSubItemsAsync(_parent.ItemSelected.Id);
            var coll = new ObservableCollection<SubItem>();
            foreach (var it in items)
            {
                coll.Add(it);
            }
            SubItemsCollection = coll;
        }

        public void RefreshAsync()
        {
            FetchSubItemsAsync();
        }

        private SubItem _itemSelected;

        public SubItem SubItemSelected
        {
            get => _itemSelected;
            set
            {
                _itemSelected = value;
               // _navService.PushView(typeof(EditSubItemViewModel).ToString());
            }
        }

        #region FetchCommand

        private ICommand _fetchItemsCommand;

        public ICommand FetchItemsCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_fetchItemsCommand == null)
                    _fetchItemsCommand = _cmdFactory.CreateCommand(FetchSubItemsAsync, () => true);
                return _fetchItemsCommand;
            }
        }


        #endregion

        #region AddItemCommand

        private ICommand _addItemCommand;

        public ICommand AddItemCommand
        {
            get
            {

                if (_addItemCommand == null)
                    _addItemCommand = _cmdFactory.CreateCommand(AddItem, () => true);
                return _addItemCommand;
            }
        }
        public void AddItem()
        {
            _appData.IsEditSubItem = false;
            _navService.PushView(typeof(SubItemViewModel).ToString());
        }
        #endregion

        #region EditItemCommand

        private ICommand _editItemCommand;


        public ICommand EditItemCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_editItemCommand == null)
                    _editItemCommand = _cmdFactory.CreateCommand(EditItem, () => true);
                return _editItemCommand;
            }
        }
        public void EditItem()
        {
            _appData.IsEditSubItem = true;
            _navService.PushView(typeof(SubItemViewModel).ToString());
        }
        #endregion

        #region SearchCommand

        private ICommand _searchCommand;


        public ICommand SearchCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_searchCommand == null)
                    _searchCommand = _cmdFactory.CreateCommand(SearchItemAsync, () => true);
                return _searchCommand;
            }
        }
        private async void SearchItemAsync()
        {
            var items = await _itemService.GetAllSubItemsAsync(_parent.ItemSelected.Id);
            var sstring = SearchString.ToLower();
            items = items.Where(i => i.Name.ToLower().Contains(sstring));
            var coll = new ObservableCollection<SubItem>();
            foreach (var it in items)
            {
                coll.Add(it);
            }
            SubItemsCollection = coll;
        }
        #endregion

    }
}
```

Comment: Many ideas. Show your xaml and the code how you bind your model then we can show how to add tap gesture to the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add TapGestureRecognizer to the image and bind the command in your ViewModel. Also, you are binding the command inside ViewCell, so you need to set the source of BindingContext.

```
<ContentPage x:Name="ABCPage">
  ...
  <Image Source="abc">
    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
      <TapGestureRecognizer
        Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.ImageCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=ABCPage}}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
  </Image>
  ...
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: @DevMonk Does this answer your question?